# Complexity class of a function with known dependency between its execution time and its input size

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Suppose I am trying to find the complexity class of a function. My data set doubles every time I evaluate the function, and each time this happens, the time it takes to execute the function increases by a factor of (X).

If we know (X), how do we find the complexity class/ O notation of the function? For example, if X is slightly over 2, then the Big-O notation is O(N log N).

Comment: Not clear enough. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Let `T(n)` be the time complexity of the function you are talking about, where `n` is the size of input data. We can write recursive equation for `T(n)`:

```
T(n) = X * T(n/2)
```

where `X` is your constant. Let's "unroll" this recursion:

```
T(n) = X * T(n/2) = X^2 * T(n/4) = X^3 * T(n/8) = ... = X^k * T(n/2^k)
```

This unrolling process should end when the parameter `k` becomes large enough to satisfy:

```
n/2^k = 1
```

which means that `n = 2^k` or `k = log(n)` (logarithm is by base 2). Also we can assume that:

```
T(1) = C
```

where `C` is some another constant. Now we look at unrolled equation and substitute `k` by `log(n)` and `T(1)` by `C`:

```
T(n) = X^log(n) * C
```

We can simplify this formula using logarithm properties:

```
T(n) = C * n^log(X)
```